# Multiplying the normal by what vector will give the center of a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I was reading the above recently (some of the notation above is confusing, $a$ is used for a vector and also a scalar..). The goal of the following what I'm trying to do is find $t$, or the distance in the ray equation:

$$\mathbf p = \mathbf o + t\mathbf d$$

($p$ is a point in the ray, $o$ is the origin, and $d$ is the direction the ray is going)

In the above excerpt from Kevin Suffern's "Ray Tracing from the Ground Up", we use the equation of the plane.

$$(\mathbf p - \mathbf c) \bullet \mathbf n = 0$$

($p$ is a random point on plane, $c$ is a fixed point on the plane (see below for how the source defines it), $n$ is a normal)

Here's how the book defines the equation of a plane (I have replaced in my question any instances of $\mathbf a$ (as in the book representing a fixed point on the plane) with $\mathbf c$ since later on we use a different $a$ as a scalar):
[image]

After subbing in and expanding for $(\mathbf o+t\mathbf d-\mathbf c)\bullet\mathbf n=0$, and comparing coefficients with the equation of the line: $at+b=0$, we get:

$$a = \mathbf d \bullet \mathbf n$$
$$b = \mathbf n \bullet (\mathbf o - \mathbf c)$$

Here's source #2:

(Note: The normal here is defined as (1, 0, 0) for planes, so indeed it comes out as a unit vector)

They derive in much the same way the equation for $a$:

$$a = \mathbf d \bullet \mathbf n$$

Then they somehow find the following:

$$b = \mathbf n \bullet(\mathbf o - u \mathbf n)$$ ($u$ is supposed to represent "distance", so very probably |$ \mathbf p - \mathbf c$| in this case, but I think they were a bit ambiguous in defining it, so I may be wrong here; $n$ is a normal of plane, $o$ is origin of the ray).

My question is:
Are $u\mathbf n$ and $\mathbf c$, the same thing? Does any scalar value multiplied with $\mathbf n$ actually equal a fixed point on the plane? If one of the sources is wrong, it's probably Source #2... but I think it's probably right. Is there any other way to interpret the constant value "distance" $u$ as other than $|p - c|$?

Could someone explain how I can reconcile equations:
$$b = \mathbf n \bullet (\mathbf o - \mathbf c)$$
and
$$b = \mathbf n \bullet(\mathbf o - u \mathbf n)$$

Comment: As in your previous question, you haven’t really defined $\mathbf c$. It doesn’t appear anywhere in the excerpt, and a plane doesn’t have a “center” since it extends to infinity in every direction. *Any* point on the plane will work for the fixed point in the equation. Also, there’s no such thing as “the” normal to a plane: there’s an infinite number of them. Often one might want to use a unit normal, which narrows it down to two choices, but you’ve not included enough from either source to tell if that’s what’s intended.

Comment: @amd I concede I was not being precise. I have updated the question to address these problems. Thank you again.

Comment: That helps a lot. I’ll come back with an answer late tomorrow if no one else gets to it first.

Comment: "(Note: The normal here is defined as (1, 0, 0) for planes, so indeed it comes out as a unit vector)" No. $(1,0,0)$ is normal *only to planes with equation $x = k$ for some constant $k$*. But planes do not have to be perpendicular to the $x$ axis. The general (non-vector) equation of a plane is $Ax + By + Cz = D$. The normal of that plane will actually be $\pm\frac {(A, B, C)}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + C^2}}$ ($\pm$ because the opposite of a normal is also a normal, so you can choose either one; the division by the square root is to make the normal a unit vector).

Comment: @PaulSinclair obviously this is true. I'm not claiming all planes have the normal (1, 0, 0). It's just how souce #2 sees the normal for all planes that they are specifically using. They do not use any planes which do not have the equation $x = k$.

Comment: Okay - from what you said, it sounded like you thought $(1,0,0)$ is always the normal, and I wanted to make sure you realized that was false. Please pardon that I don't know your education level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbf c$ and $u\mathbf n$ are not quite the same thing.

- $\mathbf c$ is an arbitrary fixed point on the plane ("fixed" because we are considering $\mathbf p$ to be the variable while sticking to a single point for $\mathbf c$, "arbitrary" because it doesn't matter which point on the plane we choose for $\mathbf c$).
- $u\mathbf n$ is - for the correct value of $u$ - a particular point on the plane.

As amd said, as a general rule, we don't consider planes as having centers. However, in analytic geometry, there is a special identifiable point on any plane: the unique point on the plane that is closest to the origin. I have heard this point called the "center" before. And that may be the case for your sources. Just realize that this is not a universal terminology.

The line connecting the origin to the closest point on the plane will necessarily be perpendicular to that plane. I.e., it will be parallel to the normal vector $\mathbf n$, which means its vector equation has form $\mathbf v = \mathbf v_0 + t\mathbf n$, where $\mathbf v_0$ is some fixed point on that line. But the origin is on the line, so we can just take $\mathbf v_0 = \mathbf 0$, which leaves us with the equation of the line being $\mathbf v = t\mathbf n$.

There is only one point where this line intersects the plane. I.e., there is a unique value $t$ such that $t\mathbf n$ is on the plane. Your source is using $u$ to represent that unique value of $t$.

Thus

- $(\mathbf p - \mathbf c)\cdot \mathbf n = 0$ gives an equation for the plane, for any fixed point $\mathbf c$ on the plane. Note that each $\mathbf c$ provides a different equation in this form.
- $u\mathbf n$ is a particular point on the plane, where $u$ is chosen to be the value of $t$ where the line $t\mathbf n$ interesects the plane.

Therefore $$(\mathbf p - u\mathbf n)\cdot \mathbf n = 0$$ is a particular equation for the plane, which easily simplifies to $$\mathbf p \cdot \mathbf n = u$$ since $\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf n = 1$. And if you express $\mathbf n = (A, B, C)$, and $\mathbf p = (x,y,z)$, this becomes $$Ax + By + Cz = u$$

Comment: Would it thus be fair to say that $u$ is the distance from the origin to $\mathbf c$, since $|\mathbf n| = 1$? So $u \mathbf n$ is just $k$ in the plane's equation $x =k$ for some constant $k$ (Normals in this source are all the unit $x$ vector)?

Comment: Only when $\mathbf c = u\mathbf n$. Remember that $\mathbf c$ denotes an arbitrary point on the plane. But, yes, $u$ is the distance from the origin to the plane.